# Updating the content of one window by opening new window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am setting the `data context` of second window with the selected row of my data grid as follow:

```
newdialog.DataContext=myGrid.SelectedItem;
```

what I want to do here is when I change the values in new window and press OK button, then it should update the data of selected row in myGrid.
The problem is when I change the data in new window, before pressing OK button, It update the data in myGrid inside my first window (even when I cancel the second window).

What else should I write in order to show data of selected row in second window?
And to update data in first window properly.
When user will press OK button, below condition will be true.

```
if (newdialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{                   
   // Something...                         
}
```

Comment: That is more of a design question - you should pass a data transfer object to your new window and only if succeeded, request for a result according to which you will update your primary window viewmodel

Comment: I guess in your bindings you have set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`,right?

Comment: No I have not set the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged